# How to show localized text and custom icons in context menu shell extensions using IExecuteCommand and verbs?

Tags: c++, winapi, contextmenu, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I was considering developing a context menu shell extension following the new Windows 7+ approach based on `IExecuteCommand`, as described in this blog post:

> [Simplifying context menu extensions with IExecuteCommand](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623)

instead of the classic `IContextMenu` approach I'm more familiar with.

I have a couple of questions about this new method:

1. How can I show **localized text** (for example, loaded from resources) in the customized menu items? In the old model, this can be simply done invoking `InsertMenu` in the `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu` implementation, and passing a string loaded from resources.
2. How can I associate and show an **icon** with my custom menu items? Again, this can be done in the old `IContextMenu`-based model, for example invoking `SetMenuItemBitmaps`. Are there specific image formats required for the menu icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IExecuteCommand` is used for shell verbs that are [registered statically in the Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers#customizing-a-shortcut-menu-using-static-verbs) and have a `"DelegateExecute"="{clsid}"` value associated with them.  The menu text for a *static* verb is taken from the *display text* that is registered for the verb<strike>, and that text is displayed as-is, it cannot be localized, as there is simply no option provided to specify an alternate source for the text. Only a real shell extension based on `IContextMenu` or `IExplorerCommand` has the option to localize text and provide icons for its custom verbs. `IExecuteCommand` does not provide that functionality</strike>.

**UPDATE**: On Windows XP and later, the display text for *static* verbs are [MUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-multilingual-user-interface)-aware, so you can provide display text that refers to a localized resource.  This is documented:

[Using Registry String Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-registry-string-redirection)

> ### Provide Resources for Shell Verb Action Strings
>
> Action strings for certain verbs, for example, "open" and "edit", are shown in the pop-up menu displayed when the user right-clicks a file in Windows Explorer. Your application does not have to specify strings for common shell verbs, as the shell has its own MUI-enabled defaults for these verbs. **However, you should provide localizable string resources for strings representing uncommon verbs.**
>
> On pre-Windows XP operating systems, strings for shell verbs in the registry are rendered using the following syntax, where verb specifies the actual verb name:
>
> ```
> HKCR\<progid>\shell\<verb>
> @ = <friendly-name>
> ```
>
> Here's an example:
>
> ```
> HKCR\Sample.app\shell\Disc
> @ = "Disconnect"
> ```
>
> **On Windows XP and later, you can use a level of indirection to make an action string depend on user interface language.** These operating systems support a MUIVerb value for definition of a MUI-compatible string. Here's an example of a registry entry for an uncommon verb:
>
> ```
> HKCR\Sample.app\shell\Disc
> @ = "Disconnect"
> "MUIVerb" = "@%systemroot%\system32\sample.exe,-9875"
> ```
>
> Your MUI application should also be able to register the old default value as a localizable string, as shown below:
>
> ```
> HKCR\Sample.app\shell\Disc
> @ = "@%systemroot%\system32\sample.exe,-9875"
> ```
>
> > Note
> >     Registration of the old default value is not recommended because it requires a different setup on Windows XP and later from the setup used on earlier operating systems.

AFAIK, you cannot provide an icon for a *static* verb to display in the context menu, though.  You do need a shell extension based on `IContextMenu` or `IExplorerCommand` for that.

Comment: You could use [MUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/using-multilingual-user-interface) to get localized labels couldn't you? If the static label used the *@dllpath,id* syntax?

Comment: @JonathanPotter good point.  I found the relevant documentation about that and have updated my answer accordingly.